# Magento White Screen FrontEnd - PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error

I was recently trying to add a javascript gallery to my development magento site and was editing code through the "page.xml" - it wasn't working so i deleted the code out of the file.

Now when i load the website it comes up with the White Screen - so googling around i did the necessary steps

- uncomment the **ini_set('display_errors', 1);**"
- added the "**ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');**

AND i could not get the error to show up... so i added the code at the bottom of this webpage (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222103/magento-white-screen-on-admin-log-in-page)

**Now it shows an PHP Load Error:**

```
Array
(
    [type] => 32
    [message] => PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    [file] => Unknown
    [line] => 0
)
```

**Could anyone point me in the right direction of what the issue could be and a possible solution??**

Anything would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO loads fine in Magento but not in external CMS](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/pdo-loads-fine-in-magento-but-not-in-external-cms)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - I simply copied my "page.xml" file from my LIVE Site to the Dev site and it fixed the problem...

Still get the PHP Load Error but that doesn't seem to be bothering the website..