# Can't login into admin area

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, password

I install Magento about 2-3 weeks ago. I've been using it for a few months in work and decided to start a new project store with it.

Then today i went to login and my username / password appeared to be wrong. I got no errors.. just refreshed to the same login screen.

I thought it might be my password so I did the forgot email thing and got the email to reset my password and I entered a new one and it still won't let me  login.

I'm using the same PC as I also do to work. What can be wrong ?

I'm using Magento 1.9.3.7

EDIT--
I just looked at the error logs and this is appearing over and over

```
    [26-Feb-2018 11:47:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded' in /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:344
Stack trace:
#0 /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(248): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->setFetchMode(2)
#1 /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(175): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#3 /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#4 /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#5 /home/*****/**domain**.com/st in /home/*****/**domain**.com/store/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 344
```

Comment: Try logging in using private/incognito window.

Comment: I just tried . That didn't work.

Comment: I've added an update from the error logs that may help.

Comment: Is your frontend working? It seems from logs that php has lost write connection to db.

Comment: Yes it's working fine. I'm able to add products to check out etc.

Comment: look into this thread https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1342/pdo-loads-fine-in-magento-but-not-in-external-cms

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable PDO extension from your server.

Comment: Will this fix my login problem ? .. how was i able to login before ?

Comment: Maybe your web server is working not stable. Because I see in your log.

Comment: My hosting provider says this
 ""I have checked the PDO extension and saw that it's already enabled for the account. It's not a server side issue, it's purely related to the Magento application and a developer can sort out the issue easily.""  --- 
 So i'm not sure where to go now.